# Thickbox jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, thickbox, shadowbox

I have a jQuerycode to preview the pictures in my website, but I do not know the difference between (single.jpg) and (single_t.jpg) in my code. Here is my code:

```
<a href="images/single.jpg" title="add a caption to title attribute / or leave blank" class="thickbox"><img src="images/single_t.jpg" alt="Single Image"/></a>
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`single.jpg` in this case is the main image file with normal resolution which will normally require more time to load

`single_t.jpg` in this case is the thumbnail (`t` is used short for `thumbnail`) of the file with smaller size. Therefore, it would load faster.

Comment: do i create 2 images in (image file)? and called this images in defrent name?

Comment: It is upto you... Although it will be better to create a thumbnail. Google thumbnail creator. There are many online ones that convert your BIG image file into a small thumbnail. And yes you need 2 different names for 2 different files. 2nd method is that you use the same file and the same file name but in the `img src` tag use `height="50px"` and `width="50px"`. 50 is just an example, but use some small number

Answer (score 0):

It might be the same image, but if single.jpg is a big, heavy image, then it would make sense for you to display just a thumbnail instead (hence the _t suffix).